# How do I use glob/regex patterns to rename files in terminal?

Tags: regex, bash, terminal, glob

I am trying to create a quick way to change the filename format to rearrange the original file name. 
EXAMPLE:

I have three files:

```
2019_12_10_Mike_Smith_item1.jpg
2016_06_24_John_Ward_item2.jpg
2011_11_18_Charlie_Coyle_item3.jpg
```

The file format for these three files is :

```
YYYY_MM_DD_Fname_Lname_item#.jpg
```

I want to rename this file with the following format:

```
Fname_Lname_item#_YYYY_MM_DD.jpg
```

So that our first file would now be:

```
Mike_Smith_item1_2019_12_10.jpg
```

I have very little experience working in Terminal/Bash and have spent the last few hours looking for ways to do this with GLOB/REGEX. I am familiar with regex, but cannot seem to figure out how to refer to the grouped items. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many regex tools support back references, i.e. `perl -pe 's/^((?:[^:_]+)_){3})(.*)\.jpg/\2_\1.jpg/'` (though that will move an underscore where you don't want one, too). Here, `\1` refers to the first parenthesized group, and `\2` to the second. (Perl in particular also exposes these as dollar variables, and prefers that you use those.)

Comment: If you want to do this in pure bash, you can use the `${BASH_REMATCH[$n]}` to refer to a match (where `$n` would be 1, 2, or 3 in your case...)

Comment: Your basic Regex pattern can be `(\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2})_(.*?)_(item\d+)`, and then use your tool of choice to sub the groups in the order `\2_\3_\1`: https://regex101.com/r/otdT2h/1/

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method which uses globs and bash's prefix/suffix removal features:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    g=${f%.jpg}
    mv -i -- "$f" "${g#*_*_*_}_${g%_${g#*_*_*_}}.jpg"
done
```

#### Example

Consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls *jpg
2011_11_18_Charlie_Coyle_item3.jpg  2016_06_24_John_Ward_item2.jpg  2019_12_10_Mike_Smith_item1.jpg
```

Now, run our command:

```
$ for f in *.jpg; do g=${f%.jpg}; mv -i -- "$f" "${g#*_*_*_}_${g%_${g#*_*_*_}}.jpg"; done
```

These are the files after:

```
$ ls *jpg
Charlie_Coyle_item3_2011_11_18.jpg  John_Ward_item2_2016_06_24.jpg  Mike_Smith_item1_2019_12_10.jpg
```

#### How it works

- `for f in *.jpg; do`

  This starts a loop over every jpg file in the current directory.
- `g=${f%.jpg}`

  This removes `.jpg` from the end of the file name and assigns the result to the variable `g`.
- `mv -i -- "$f" "${g#*_*_*_}_${g%_${g#*_*_*_}}.jpg"`

  This renames file `$f` to `${g#*_*_*_}_${g%_${g#*_*_*_}}.jpg`.  `${g#*_*_*_}` is the file name after removing the date.  `${g%_${g#*_*_*_}}` is the date.

  Here's an example showing what happens step by step.  Let's start by assigning a file name to variable `f`:

  ```
  $ f=2011_11_18_Charlie_Coyle_item3.jpg
  ```

  `g` will be the file name without the suffix:

  ```
  $ g=${f%.jpg}
  ```

  The file name without the date is:

  ```
  $ echo "${g#*_*_*_}"
  Charlie_Coyle_item3
  ```

  The date without the rest of the file name is:

  ```
  $ echo "${g%_${g#*_*_*_}}"
  2011_11_18
  ```
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.